# SQL инъекция формы входа на сайтк

Tags: php, mysql, sql, веб-программирование, безопасность

Всем привет, получил задание проверить на уязвимость вход на локальный сайт с электронным расписанием. Пробовал стандартные запросы типа: `' OR 1=1; /*`, но ничего не получается. Вот код сайта:

```
    <?php
    session_start();
    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style1.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="form-wrap">
        <h2 class="header-title" >Главная страница</h2>
    <form action="index.php" method="post" class="forma">
   <?
    //  вся процедура работает на сессиях. Именно в ней хранятся данные  пользователя, пока он находится на сайте. Очень важно запустить их в  самом начале странички!!!
    if (isset($_POST['login'])) { 
        $login = $_POST['login']; 
        if ($login == '') { 
            unset($login);
        } 
    } //заносим введенный пользователем логин в переменную $login, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
    if (isset($_POST['password'])) { 
        $password=$_POST['password']; 
        if ($password ==''){ 
            unset($password);
        }
     }
    //заносим введенный пользователем пароль в переменную $password, если он пустой, то уничтожаем переменную
    if (empty($login) or empty($password))//если пользователь не ввел логин или пароль, то выдаем ошибку и останавливаем скрипт
    {   
        echo ("Вы ввели не всю информацию, вернитесь назад и заполните все поля!");?>
        <input type="submit" name="close" value="Назад" class="btn">
        <?
        exit ();
    }
    //если логин и пароль введены,то обрабатываем их, чтобы теги и скрипты не работали, мало ли что люди могут ввести
    $login = stripslashes($login);
    $login = htmlspecialchars($login);
    $password = stripslashes($password);
    $password = htmlspecialchars($password);
    //удаляем лишние пробелы
    $login = trim($login);
    $password = trim($password);
    // подключаемся к базе
    include ("bd.php");// файл bd.php должен быть в той же папке, что и все остальные, если это не так, то просто измените путь 
    $privilage = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT privilage FROM user WHERE login='$login'");
    $priv = mysqli_fetch_array($privilage);
    $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM user WHERE login='$login'");
    //извлекаем из базы все данные о пользователе с введенным логином
    $myrow = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

        $password = md5($password ."sdf");
        //если существует, то сверяем пароли
        if ($myrow['password']==$password) {
            //если пароли совпадают, то запускаем пользователю сессию! Можете его поздравить, он вошел!
            $_SESSION['login']=$myrow['login'];
            $_SESSION['id']=$myrow['id'];
           //эти данные очень часто используются, вот их и будет "носить с собой" вошедший пользователь
           if ($priv['privilage'] != NULL){
               ?>
               <div class="login">
               <?
               echo "Вы зашли как <br>";
               echo "администратор ".$_SESSION['login']." ";
               ?>
               </div>
               <? 
           }
            else{
               ?>
               <div class="login">
               <?
               echo "Вы вошли как <br>";
               echo "".$_SESSION['login'].""; 
               ?>
               </div> 
               <?
            }
        }
        else {
            //если пароли не сошлись
            echo ("Извините, введённый вами логин или пароль неверный.");
            ?>
            <input type="submit" name="close" value="Назад" class="btn">
            <?
            exit();
        }
    ?>      
        <input type="submit" name="close" value="Выйти" class="btn">
       </form>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: от sql инъекции вас обезопасит не вот это вот все с бубнами, а банальная передача в запрос через плейсхолдеры и параметры, а-ля `execute('... where login =:login', ['login' => $login])`,

Comment: Обращаться напрямую в массив $_POST тоже плохой стиль, лучше использовать функцию filter_input, там сразу можно выполнять фильтрацию и очистку данных, аналогично stripslashes и htmlspecialchars, например filter_input(INPUT_POST,'login',FILTER_SANITIZE_ADD_SLASHES)

Comment: Для запросов на mysqli лучше использовать "Подготавливаемые запросы"
https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php